# jQuery find / closest li element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i try to dynamically surround an image-tag with a link

my case:

```
if (a === b) {
  console.log('my iamge-tag is : ' + $(e).html());
}
```

in $(e).html() i have at this moment my desired image-tag:

```
<img class="xyz" src="http://images.zzz.com/images/123456/original.png">
```

in the DOM this image is in a ordered list just like this way:

```
<li class="">
  <img class="xyz" src="http://images.zzz.com/images/111111/original.png">
</li>
<li class="">
  <img class="xyz" src="http://images.zzz.com/images/222222/original.png">
</li>
<li class="">
  <img class="xyz" src="http://images.zzz.com/images/123456/original.png">
</li>
```

how could i manage it to surround my desired image-tag with a link?

```
<li class="">
  <a href="http://www.example.com"><img class="xyz" src="http://images.zzz.com/images/123456/original.png"></a>
</li>
```

Comment: `$(e).wrap('<a href="http://www.example.com"></a>');` will work perfectly.

Comment: awesome, i didn't know wrap() - thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery **[.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)** funnction,

```
$('img').wrap('<a href="http://www.example.com"></a>');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5LrQk/12/)**

- Use your specific `img` selector if needed, in the place of mine.
- Use `wrapAll()` in case you have to append all elements with same HTML.

Answer (score 0):

wrap() function should work. I tested it like this.

if (a == b) {

$("li img").wrap("http://www.google.com'>");

}